# What does .fadeIn() act on? | What does $("#id") return?

Tags: jquery

Here is the [jQuery API for fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

If I use a simple id like this.

```
$("#id").fadeIn();
```

What does `$("#id")` return, is it a simple DOM element?

I looked again in the jQuery API but they don't note the return type in the function prototype:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

As a side question:

If it is a simple DOM element, how does jQuery associate fadeIn() with the returned element? How does the compiler know to find fadeIn() for the element?

Comment: Hiro, you really, really need to start paying attention to your tag spelling ... again :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a jQuery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), it returns an array of DOM elements wrapped in [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). You can unwrap the original DOM element by using:

```
$("#id")[0]
```

What's nice about the wrapping object is that it delegates methods to every element of wrapped array, e.g. if you use:

```
$('div.content').fadeIn();
```

It will fade in all `<div>` elements with `class="content"` found in your document.

Comment: Should only return one element ( only one id is allowed per... ) wrapped in an jQuery object correct?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: that's correct, but in general selector can return arbitrary number of elements, e.g. $('img') - all `<img/>` tags.

Comment: What is a jQuery object exactly, the documentation you provided is the same documentation I posted...it is for the jQuery function which has no information on what is returned...from the syntax it appears to be an array?

Answer (score 2):

`What does $("#id") return, is it a simple DOM element?`

No, it is a DOM element wrapped in a jQuery object.

There are a few ways to unwrap it, such as `$("#id").get(0)` or `$("#id")[0]`. From benchmarking, `$("#id")[0]` seems to be the fastest.

`What does .fadeIn() act on?`

fadeIn calls this jquery code:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
function (d, e, f) {
 //.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )
 return this.animate(b, d, e, f);
}
```

which then calls the animate code:

```
animate: function( prop, speed, easing, callback ) {
    var optall = jQuery.speed(speed, easing, callback);

    if ( jQuery.isEmptyObject( prop ) ) {
        return this.each( optall.complete );
    }

    return this[ optall.queue === false ? "each" : "queue" ](function() {
        // XXX 'this' does not always have a nodeName when running the
        // test suite

        var opt = jQuery.extend({}, optall), p,
            isElement = this.nodeType === 1,
            hidden = isElement && jQuery(this).is(":hidden"),
            self = this;

        for ( p in prop ) {
            var name = jQuery.camelCase( p );

            if ( p !== name ) {
                prop[ name ] = prop[ p ];
                delete prop[ p ];
                p = name;
            }

            if ( prop[p] === "hide" && hidden || prop[p] === "show" && !hidden ) {
                return opt.complete.call(this);
            }

            if ( isElement && ( p === "height" || p === "width" ) ) {
                // Make sure that nothing sneaks out
                // Record all 3 overflow attributes because IE does not
                // change the overflow attribute when overflowX and
                // overflowY are set to the same value
                opt.overflow = [ this.style.overflow, this.style.overflowX, this.style.overflowY ];

                // Set display property to inline-block for height/width
                // animations on inline elements that are having width/height
                // animated
                if ( jQuery.css( this, "display" ) === "inline" &&
                        jQuery.css( this, "float" ) === "none" ) {
                    if ( !jQuery.support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout ) {
                        this.style.display = "inline-block";

                    } else {
                        var display = defaultDisplay(this.nodeName);

                        // inline-level elements accept inline-block;
                        // block-level elements need to be inline with layout
                        if ( display === "inline" ) {
                            this.style.display = "inline-block";

                        } else {
                            this.style.display = "inline";
                            this.style.zoom = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( jQuery.isArray( prop[p] ) ) {
                // Create (if needed) and add to specialEasing
                (opt.specialEasing = opt.specialEasing || {})[p] = prop[p][1];
                prop[p] = prop[p][0];
            }
        }

        if ( opt.overflow != null ) {
            this.style.overflow = "hidden";
        }

        opt.curAnim = jQuery.extend({}, prop);

        jQuery.each( prop, function( name, val ) {
            var e = new jQuery.fx( self, opt, name );

            if ( rfxtypes.test(val) ) {
                e[ val === "toggle" ? hidden ? "show" : "hide" : val ]( prop );

            } else {
                var parts = rfxnum.exec(val),
                    start = e.cur() || 0;

                if ( parts ) {
                    var end = parseFloat( parts[2] ),
                        unit = parts[3] || "px";

                    // We need to compute starting value
                    if ( unit !== "px" ) {
                        jQuery.style( self, name, (end || 1) + unit);
                        start = ((end || 1) / e.cur()) * start;
                        jQuery.style( self, name, start + unit);
                    }

                    // If a +=/-= token was provided, we're doing a relative animation
                    if ( parts[1] ) {
                        end = ((parts[1] === "-=" ? -1 : 1) * end) + start;
                    }

                    e.custom( start, end, unit );

                } else {
                    e.custom( start, val, "" );
                }
            }
        });

        // For JS strict compliance
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: As a side, do you know what kind of object it is...a function object, an object literal, etc.?  What is a jQuery object?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - A jQuery object is an instantiated jQuery module with all the bells and whistles that jQuery includes such as hooks to attach event handlers and pointers to the passed target.

Comment: wow...so it just uses `this` there is nothing complicated...the method just knows...oh...snap! that would break jslint...using `this` with out `new`

Comment: `return this.animate(b, d, e, f)` violates strict I believe.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - When `fadeIn` is used it is placed in an array as a flag. jQuery then iterates through those flags and for each one set calls that code. You can see it here: `// Generate shortcuts for custom animations
jQuery.each({
 slideDown: genFx("show", 1),
 slideUp: genFx("hide", 1),
 slideToggle: genFx("toggle", 1),
 fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
 fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" },
 fadeToggle: { opacity: "toggle" }
}, function( name, props ) {
 jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, easing, callback ) {
  return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );
 };
});`